# Constructor requirements in C++11 for POD

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are Aggregates and PODs and how/why are they special?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)

What kind of constructors can structs in C++11 have to keep this struct as POD?

Only initializer-list acceptable? Or maybe there are no any restrictions?

Answer (score 1):

You need a defaulted default constructor so that it is trivial:

```
struct pot
{
    constexpr pot() noexcept = default;

    pot(int a, float b) : x(a), y(b) { }

    int x;
    float y;
};
```

The `constexpr` and `noexcept` are optional, but we might as well.

Usage:

```
pot p;         // OK
pot q(1, 1.5); // also OK
```

Comment: Why are you use constexpr for constructor here?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov: You might as well offer the strongest possible guarantees, non? That way you can use the type in constant expressions.